# How could I create a two color background for my app, I'm not trying to make a gradient, so far that's all the solutions I've been seeing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Screenshot of a mobile app ui design.

[image: mobile app ui]

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with this widget and follow [flutter.dev/development/ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: _title, home: SampleW());
  }
}

class SampleW extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .4,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: constraints.maxWidth * .2,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight, // will get by column
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will give you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
Scaffold (
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              body: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(12),topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
                  ),
                ),
              )
          )
```